# Is it possible to add multiple SetExpressions within an IF statement?

Tags: qlikview

I am having troubles trying to make a graph work. I am not entirely sure if this is possible, thus me asking here. I have below graph, which has the expression: 
`=Count{<Year='2014','2015','2016'},Month='Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT sicknumber)`

So it doesnt change with whatever selection has been made in the filters. it always shows 2014, 2015, 2016

[image]

I want to be able to make the graph non static based on the filter that is given. If I select year 2015 I want to show the previous year and the year after. so when selecting 2013 I want to see 2012, 2013 and 2014. I have made the following expression:

```
=
if(Jaar = '2016',(Count({<Jaar={'2015','2016'},Maand={'Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)),
if(Jaar = '2015',(Count({<Jaar={'2014','2015','2016'},Maand={'Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)),
if(Jaar = '2014',(Count({<Jaar={'2013','2014','2015'},Maand={'Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)),
if(Jaar = '2013',(Count({<Jaar={'2012','2013','2014'},Maand={'Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)),
if(Jaar = '2012',(Count({<Jaar={'2011','2012','2013'},Maand={'Jan','Feb','Mrt','Apr','Mei','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'}>}DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)))))))
```

it seems however that it ignores the set expression and just show the year given in the filter. How would I go around this.

When using the same statement to just calculate to total unique values in a text object, it does seem to be able to calculate the correct value there.

how would I go around this, of is it even possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=Count({<Jaar={$(=Max(Jaar) - 1), $(=Max(Jaar)), $(=Max(Jaar) + 1)}, Maand>} DISTINCT Ziekte_Volgnummer)
```

Seems to be the right answer.